# On which mobile analytics SDK can I define different types of users?

Tags: ios, flurry, localytics

I'm building an iOS app and would like to use a analytics tool (Flurry, localytics or others).
My app will have 2 types of users, where some users can be of the 1st type, some can be of the 2nd type and some will be both kinds.
On which analytics tool can I get adequate reports that take these 2 types into account? 
Is there some kind of "tag" that I can use to identify the types of users, and then see those in the reports? For example, a report that shows users only from a certain type.

Answer (score 0):

On Flurry, you can use the setUserID to log the user's assigned ID or username in your system after identifying the user. Please be sure not to use this method to pass any private or confidential information about the user.

(Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I now see the also Google Mobile Analytics and Localytics has this feature. Is there any comparison table that compares between the 3 services?

Comment: There's no comparison table as per my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The [Quantcast app measurement SDK](https://info.quantcast.com/MeasureApps_mk.html) allows you do exactly what you are asking. It is the "labels" feature of their SDK. It allows you to create audience segments against which you create reports for those users with a given label. This is different than setting a user ID (which the Quantcast SDK allows, but not requires, you to do too) in that a label is simply a tag that many users can share. Multiple labels can be assigned to a given user, and a user's labels can change over time.

(Full disclosure: I work at Quantcast. Also, as of July 2013, the reporting available against labels is rapidly evolving and improving).